# How to add color to a multi-category bar plot in Plotly while maintaining the original order of data?

Tags: r, plotly

How can I add color to a multicategory plot in Plotly using a third variable, while keeping the initial order of the data?

I was able to generate a multicategory plot:

```
plot_ly(data_test, x = c(~X1, ~X2 ), y = ~Y, type = 'bar',

        width = 1500, height = 500, showlegend=T )%>%

  add_lines(y = 20, line=list(width = 0.5, dash="dot"), showlegend=F)
```

However, when I try to add color with a third variable X3, the plot does not show up as expected:

```
plot_ly(data_test, x = c(~X1, ~X2 ), y = ~Y, type = 'bar',

        width = 1500, height = 500, color =~X3, showlegend=T )%>%

  add_lines(y = 4000, line=list(width = 0.5, dash="dot"), showlegend=F)
```

The plot no longer displays correctly. I suspect that the issue has to do with the order of the data. Is there a way to add color to the bars while keeping the initial order of the data intact?

Here's my data:

```
data_test = structure(list(X1 = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1",

"S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2",

"S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2",

"S2", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3",

"S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4",

"S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5",

"S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S5", "S6", "S6",

"S6", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S7", "S7", "S7",

"S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S8", "S8", "S8",

"S8", "S8", "S8", "S8", "S8", "S8", "S8", "S8", "S9", "S9", "S9",

"S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S10", "S10", "S10",

"S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10",

"S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S11", "S11", "S11",

"S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11",

"S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11", "S11",

"S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S14",

"S14", "S14", "S14", "S14", "S14", "S14", "S14", "S14", "S14",

"S14", "S14", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15",

"S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S16", "S16", "S16",

"S16", "S16", "S16", "S16", "S16", "S17", "S17", "S17", "S17",

"S17", "S17", "S18", "S18", "S19", "S19", "S19", "S19", "S19",

"S19", "S19", "S19", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20",

"S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S21", "S21",

"S21", "S21", "S21", "S21", "S21", "S21", "S22", "S22", "S22",

"S22", "S22", "S22", "S22", "S22", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23",

"S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23",

"S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24",

"S24", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24",

"S24", "S24", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S25",

"S25", "S25", "S25", "S25", "S26", "S26", "S26", "S26", "S26",

"S26", "S26", "S27", "S27", "S27", "S27", "S27", "S27", "S27",

"S27", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28",

"S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S28", "S29", "S29",

"S29", "S29", "S29", "S29", "S29", "S29", "S29", "S29", "S29",

"S29", "S29", "S29", "S29", "S30", "S30", "S30", "S30", "S30",

"S30", "S30", "S30", "S30", "S30", "S31", "S31", "S31", "S31",

"S31", "S31", "S31", "S31", "S31", "S31", "S31", "S31", "S31",

"S31", "S31", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32",

"S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S32", "S33", "S33",

"S33", "S33", "S33", "S33", "S34", "S34", "S35", "S35", "S35",

"S35", "S35", "S35", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36",

"S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36", "S36",

"S37", "S37", "S38", "S38", "S38", "S38", "S45", "S45", "S45",

"S46", "S46", "S46", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47",

"S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S48", "S48", "S48",

"S48", "S48", "S48", "S48", "S48", "S48", "S48", "S48", "S48",

"S48", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49",

"S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S49", "S50", "S50", "S50",

"S52", "S52", "S52", "S53"), X2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,

8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,

12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,

7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,

1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,

15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,

9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L,

3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,

7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,

12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,

8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L,

21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,

7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,

10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L,

4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L,

4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,

6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,

6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L,

1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,

15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L,

4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,

5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L,

4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L,

3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,

8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,

7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,

1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L,

9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L,

2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,

11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L,

13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,

14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), X3 = c("P3", "P3", "P3", "P1",

"P1", "P3", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P2", "P3", "P2", "P3",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P3", "P2", "P3", "P2", "P3", "P2", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P2", "P3", "P2", "P3",

"P2", "P3", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P2",

"P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P2", "P3", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1",

"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1",

"P1", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2",

"P2", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3",

"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3",

"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3",

"P2", "P3", "P3", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2"), Y = c(58,

42.83, 6.67, 531.17, 110.5, 69.67, 512.33, 15.33, 11.33, 92.67,

500.33, 1775.33, 122.83, 14, 1248.5, 150.83, 10.67, 41.83, 12.67,

21.67, 46.67, 131.83, 10.17, 8.67, 11.17, 12.5, 8.33, 131.17,

11, 62.33, 43.5, 43.5, 8, 8, 323.5, 323.5, 716, 172, 3883.33,

52.67, 620.17, 163.83, 678.5, 4.67, 5.67, 161.5, 11.5, 842.67,

228.17, 10.17, 50.33, 39.5, 337, 9.33, 22.67, 10.67, 157.5, 40.83,

77, 271.17, 7.17, 8.5, 401.5, 20.67, 12, 431.83, 431.83, 312.67,

312.67, 9, 9, 13.33, 869, 21.5, 189.33, 98.5, 64.5, 11.33, 14.5,

24.83, 9.5, 22.83, 8.5, 8.5, 154, 12.83, 81, 67.17, 1027, 62.33,

837.5, 1841.17, 12, 649.67, 31.17, 12.83, 121, 438.33, 95, 9,

1598.33, 180.67, 653.5, 4631.17, 9.67, 95.17, 349.5, 656.5, 6.17,

176.67, 586, 7.33, 672.67, 575.5, 359.67, 17.33, 15.67, 17.17,

12.83, 152.67, 17.67, 28.67, 471.17, 18, 18, 8, 8, 204.5, 204.5,

7, 7, 812.17, 122.5, 332, 8.17, 375.83, 30.17, 11.17, 416.33,

416.33, 48.5, 48.5, 13.67, 13.67, 18.83, 18.83, 5.83, 5.83, 104.5,

9.67, 14.83, 8, 6071.33, 9.17, 337.5, 8.17, 11, 12.17, 3900.5,

1252.33, 565, 13.33, 379, 540.17, 7.83, 84.17, 59, 2333.83, 1220,

6, 24.33, 422.33, 65.67, 291.67, 447.5, 11.33, 174, 1325.17,

20.83, 24, 1876.83, 39.5, 70.83, 449.5, 105.33, 203, 421, 421,

35.83, 73.5, 12.83, 516.5, 6.83, 4303.83, 514.5, 60.17, 13.17,

18.17, 135, 860.33, 2440.5, 8961.33, 5.17, 196.17, 50, 129, 1618.67,

42.17, 10.5, 4368, 531.67, 404.67, 484.83, 484.83, 6.5, 6.5,

33.67, 174.5, 174.5, 2682.67, 723.67, 8.83, 3349.17, 750.17,

99.5, 1698.17, 1380.67, 36, 159.5, 6.83, 1227.33, 6.67, 12.17,

239.17, 5294.17, 67.83, 31.33, 23.33, 23.5, 37.83, 20.5, 9.5,

14.5, 98.5, 695.33, 7.67, 3.67, 19.67, 7.67, 9.5, 15.5, 86.33,

86.33, 41, 7.33, 29.33, 31, 223.83, 946.5, 5.5, 12.17, 48, 18,

196.67, 58.5, 57.17, 697.67, 28.83, 326, 7.33, 1081.5, 10.33,

305.83, 52, 52, 22.5, 22.5, 307.5, 39.5, 522.83, 181.17, 15,

11.67, 58.17, 58.17, 503.17, 503.17, 4.67, 12, 3325, 20.67, 50.17,

75.83, 138.5, 83.83, 953.67, 649, 3601.33, 3601.33, 6.5, 63.83,

72.5, 34.83, 27.17, 5.83, 8.5, 104, 104, 6.17, 6.17, 19.17, 19.17,

10, 40.67, 171.5, 5.83, 83.83, 258.17, 10, 11.67, 10.5, 5.5,

306.33, 4260.33, 308.33, 62.5, 129.5, 4.83, 100.83, 6, 23.5,

50.17, 84.83, 10.17, 1237, 92.5, 13.33, 15, 6.83, 175.67, 9.67,

13.83, 7.5, 93.83, 12.5, 9, 1024.83, 13.17, 12.33, 23.5, 4.67,

6.17, 507.5, 38.33, 26, 418.17, 7.67, 33.5, 98.17, 415, 21.33,

78.67, 10.17, 224.83, 11.5, 5.83, 182.67, 6, 45.5, 1695.17, 20.17,

1881.5, 4148, 14, 4082.83, 1996.33, 32, 84.5, 279, 1081.33, 333.67,

566.17, 31.5, 17.83, 54.33, 1073.67, 328.33, 13.83, 34.5, 7.33,

553.67, 35.5, 343.67, 8.17, 12.17, 195.5, 61.5, 26.67, 1760.17,

515.83, 128.17, 218.67, 20.83, 19.83, 98.67, 5157, 365.83, 3685.17,

593.83, 48.17, 88.83, 76.33, 112.83, 32.5, 60, 13, 1054.67, 10.33,

9, 5.33, 290.33, 60.83, 34.33, 11.5, 26.33, 40.67, 59.5, 14.17,

8.83, 13, 58.5, 14.67, 71.5, 392.83, 18.67, 735.17, 178.5, 7,

10.17, 29.17, 83.67, 18.5, 15.5, 9.17, 5.67, 10.67, 582.17, 19.83,

4.17, 6445.83, 181.5, 8.83, 544.67)), row.names = c(NA, -453L

), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance !